# Unable to debug with dual debugger on Nokia 7.1

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, nokia

I'm trying to debug NDK application on my Nokia 7.1 from Android Studio (3.4.1) but I'm getting this error:

```
Error running 'app': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8600): java.io.IOException
```

I can connect to device with ndk, run app without debugging and even debug application using Java debugger (Run/Debug configurations -> Debugger -> Debug type: Java). Also debugging application C code is working on another phone (CAT S60).

First I was thinking about debugger connection timeout, so I increased it to 500000ms. This didn't help.

Attaching to running process is working but only Java or only Native debugger. Dual debugger failed to connect Java part and application is waiting for debugger.

Here is message from debugger console:

```
Debugger attached to process 29042
Timed out waiting for java debugger to attach

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Does anybody have experience how to run dual debugger on Nokia 7.1?